# Android - standard layout folder, which screen size?

Tags: android, layout, screen

I'm implementing an application and I want to support all screen sizes. I have 4 layout folders: layout, layout-small, layout-large and layout-xlarge.

Which screen size supports the standard layout folder? Is it even necessary?

Comment: The layout folders have nothing to do with screen SIZE.  Only screen DENSITY.

Answer (score 2):

> Which screen size supports the standard layout folder?

In your case, it will depend on what files are in what directories.

Let's say that you have `main.xml` in `layout/`, and not in any of the other three candidates. Then, `setContentView(R.layout.main)` will use the copy in `layout/`.

Now, let's say that you add a revised version of `main.xml` in `layout-xlarge/`. On an `-xlarge` device, Android will use the `layout-xlarge/` version of `main.xml`, and on other screen sizes, Android will use the `layout/` version of `main.xml`.

Now, let's say that you add a third `main.xml` version, this time in `layout-small/`. Android will still use the `layout-xlarge/` copy of `main.xml` for `-xlarge` devices. However, all other devices will use `layout-small/`, and the `layout/` copy of `main.xml` will be ignored. Android will not try to shrink a layout from a larger size (e.g., `-xlarge` layout on a `-normal` device), but it will try to expand a layout from a smaller size (e.g., a `-small` layout on a `-normal` device).

What I tend to do is use `layout/` for:

- Layouts that do not need different versions for different sizes
- Layouts to be used on `-normal` devices (as I rarely support `-small`)

I then use `layout-large/`, `layout-xlarge/`, or their Android 3.1+ replacements (e.g., `layout-w720dp/`) for layouts to be used on larger screen sizes.

However, that is just my particular style, and you are welcome to do what you want, within the usage rules described above.

Answer (score 1):

using modern notation is a better solution:

```
/layout // for phones
/layout-sw600dp // for 7 inch tablets
/layout-sw720dp // for 10 inch tablets
```

Answer (score 0):

In popular:

Mdpi screen smartphone is cheap
Hdpi screen smartphone is expensive.

If you use layouts only mdpi folder, this layout will be used for all screens

Legend:

```
layout-small = ldpi
layout = mdpi
layout-large = hdpi
layout-xlarge = xhdpi
```